# How to set Primary Key while creating a PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, primary-key, pyspark

I basically created a glue dynamic frame from the table I read "raw_tb". Then, I've converted the dynamic frame into Spark Dataframe using .todf() method. Now,  I'm trying to create 2 separate dataframes from raw_df.

```
# Spark Context Object
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)

#sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# Boto Client Objects
client = boto3.client('glue', region_name=REGION_NAME)
s3client = boto3.client('s3', region_name=REGION_NAME)

RAW_TABLE = "raw_tb"
```

table_read_df=glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(RAW_DATABASE,RAW_TABLE)

```
raw_df = table_read_df.toDF()

policy_tbl = raw_df['policynumber','status','startdate','expirationdate']
location_tbl = raw_df['locationid','city','county','state','zip']
```

Here, I would like to set the "policynumber" column in policy_tbl and "locationid"  column in location_tbl as primary keys. I'm not sure how that's possible. Please help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeI0N.png

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. As a heads up this is not a great question for stack overflow yet. Please add some code you've tried and the error you ran into, and you are more likely to get help here.

Comment: Spark dataframes don't have keys. You can _treat_ a single column as a primary key, but you'd have to enforce those properties yourself. On creation and basic operations you can refer to the [official tutorial](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#overview)